# Google Charts - How to line break axis label into two rows? (Multiple X Axes)

Tags: javascript, svg, line-breaks, google-visualization

I have my google line chart which looks something like this:

```
10|                        .
  |            .....----''' ''--.
09| .-----'''''                  ''-
  |                                 '.
08|                                   \
  |                                    '.
07|                                      '.
  |________________________________________________________
   2012/12/27 12:01    2012/12/26 12:22    2012/12/25 11:33
```

And I want it to look like this (notice the X-Axis label):

```
10|                        .
  |            .....----''' ''-.
09| .-----'''''                 \
  |                              '.
08|                                \
  |                                 '.
07|                                   '.
  |_______________________________________________
   2012/12/27          2012/12/26       2012/12/25
   12:01               12:22            11:33
```

I tried adding `<br>`, `\n`, and `\r` but no luck.

I looked through the documentation and the closest thing I found was `hAxis.maxTextLines` but there is no `minTextLines` options so I couldn't figure out how to force it. How can I do this?

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that this is possible when creating charts by linking to google. You just have to set the `chxt` variable with extra x values (however many more x axes you need): `chxt=y,x,x`. And then for each x axis, you set what the labels will be with the `chxl` variable. `chxl=1:|2012/12/27|2012/12/26|2012/12/25|2:|12:01|12:22|11:33`

For example:

[**http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|2012/12/27|2012/12/26|2012/12/25|2:|12:01|12:22|11:33&chxr=0,7,10&chxt=y,x,x&chs=360x240&cht=bvg&chco=000000&chd=t1:9,10,7&cht=lc&chds=7,10**](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:%7C2012/12/27%7C2012/12/26%7C2012/12/25%7C2:%7C12:01%7C12:22%7C11:33&chxr=0,7,10&chxt=y,x,x&chs=360x240&cht=bvg&chco=000000&chd=t1:9,10,7&cht=lc&chds=7,10)

But the way I am creating my charts is through JavaScript. This way:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');

  //Populate data

  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart')).
    draw(data, {curveType: 'function',
                chartArea: {left: 70, top: 50, width: '100%', height: '85%'},
                width: 950, height: 800,
                interpolateNulls: true,
                pointSize: 5,
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                vAxis: {title: 'Count', viewWindow: {min: 7, max: 10}},
                hAxis: {title: 'Date', viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 3}}
               });
});
```

So I need to figure out a way how to do this using this format/API. How can I do it this way?

Comment: @JSuar - You definitely earned the bounty but I am still trying to implement your solution.

Comment: I hear ya. It's not the nicest solution. [Here's a cleaned up version using your code above](http://jsbin.com/eyokec/1/edit). The repeated x-axis data could also be collapsed into one array so you don't have to store it twice.

Comment: Did my solution above help? If so I can update my answer.

Comment: Yes it did. Go ahead and update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Answer updated. I'm glad I was able to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Final Update

**Working Example:** http://jsbin.com/eyokec/1/ ([edit version](http://jsbin.com/eyokec/1/edit))

Well, as usual, some digging around yielded a few possible solutions. I was only successful at getting one to work but at least you know it's possible at this point. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702920/1085891) from [Insert Links into Google Charts api data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701772/insert-links-into-google-charts-api-data/12702920#12702920) provided the working solution above.

```
  // Note: You will probably need to tweak these deltas
  // for your labels to position nicely.
  var xDelta = 35;
  var yDelta = 13;
  var years = ['2012/12/27|12:01','2012/12/26|12:22','2012/12/25|11:33','2012/12/24|11:33'];
  $('text').each(function(i, el) {
      if (years.indexOf(el.textContent) != -1) {
          var g = el.parentNode;
          var x = el.getAttribute('x');
          var y = el.getAttribute('y');
          var width = el.getAttribute('width') || 70;
          var height = el.getAttribute('height') || 35;
  
          // A "ForeignObject" tag is how you can inject HTML into an SVG document.
         var fo = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignObject");
          fo.setAttribute('x', x - xDelta);
          fo.setAttribute('y', y - yDelta);
          fo.setAttribute('height', height);
          fo.setAttribute('width', width);

          var body = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "BODY");
          var p = document.createElement("P");

          p.setAttribute("style", "font-size:.8em; font-family:Arial;text-align:center;color:#555;");
          p.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace('|','<br />');

          body.appendChild(p);
          fo.appendChild(body);
  
          // Remove the original SVG text and replace it with the HTML.
          g.removeChild(el);
          g.appendChild(fo);
      }
  });
```

The above code work but, understandably, is far from ideal. It's just a proof of concept that you can hopefully use. I saw other similar questions about updating SVG files but I couldn't get them to work. The above code might be able to update th SVG `<text>` nodes relying on `<tspan>` for multi-line support. I might try to get that to work at some point.

#### Tests

- Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m: PASS
- Firefox 17.0.1: PASS (more height needed)
- IE9: FAIL (not sure why)

#### References

- [Manipulating SVG Documents Using ECMAScript (Javascript) and the DOM](http://www.carto.net/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/)
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- jQuery SVG: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

---

### Update 0

Also, it appears that Google Image Charts API is now deprecated.

> Important: The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been [officially deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms).

So, although you can create the chart as an example of what you would like, it's possible that functionality was not brought over to Google Chart Tools.

That said, I did find this [Chart Wizard](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard) that will help create the necessary JavaScript to embed your chart with the Visualization API.

[image: Google Chart Image Example]

---

### Original

<s>Doesn't appear possible.</s> You could force it using [hAxis.minTextSpacing](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?hl=en). It works but that's certainly not the purpose of that configuration option. [You could also pull the labels out and handle them via HTML](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-chart-api@googlegroups.com/msg01325.html), but I know that's not ideal either.

Answer (score 8):

I used:

> hAxis: {format:'MMM dd, yyy \nHH:mm'}

in my options array and Google API formatted it as

```
Mar 05, 2014
   16:00
```

Comment: Why is this not the top voted answer!?  Simple and to the point, add the line break where you need.

Comment: Great for Continuous X Axis (Date, Number...), but not suitable for Discrete X Axis (String) charts, like my one.  :(

Comment: Yes, this should be the solution to adding multiple lines in the axis labels. Thank you!

Comment: You may get a syntax error when using \n on certain charts when using an arrayToDataTable. Using back ticks "First Line`\n` Second line" will process this as a literal for the line break and give you two lines.

Answer (score 3):

Put a line break `\n` where needed
e.g.

```
var data = [
    ["Days", "Pressure"],
    ["Mon\n16", 20],
    ["Tue\n17", 16],
    ["Wen\n18", 10],
    ["Thr\n19", 16],
    ["Fri\n20", 17]
];
```

[Result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7IvM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "\\n" instead of "\n", its working fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was also PHP single- vs double-quotes:

BAD `date( 'Y\nM' )`

BETTER `date( "Y\nM" )`