# Putting an html tag into a google chart using google visualization

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using google charts in a website and want to make the column names into links rather than strings.

But when I put the  tags into the chart it displays them as strings.
I have set {allowHtml:true} but still no luck.

It displays the column name as `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>` rather than `Visit W3Schools` and is a string not a link.
The code I am using is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Job State',  'Job Numbers'],
              ['<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>',   @Model.jobCount],
              ['<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>',   @Model.liveJobCount],
              ['<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>',   @Model.draftJobCount],
              ['<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>',  @Model.closedJobCount]
            ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data,{allowHtml:true},
            {title:"Current Jobs Statuses",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Job Type"}}
        );

    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701772/insert-links-into-google-charts-api-data

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong format of quotation marks and slash. You have to use \" and / instead.

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Job State',  'Job Numbers'],
          ['<a href=\"http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools<\/a>',   @Model.jobCount],
          ['<a href=\"http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools<\/a>',   @Model.liveJobCount],
          ['<a href=\"http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools<\/a>',   @Model.draftJobCount],
          ['<a href=\"http:\/\/www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools<\/a>',  @Model.closedJobCount]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to use a "click" event handler on the chart, and parse the event information for targetID to filter out all clicks other than those on axis labels:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (e) {
    // match the targetID of the clicked element to an hAxis label
    // and capture the index of the label if matched
    var match = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#\d+#label#(\d+)/);
    if (match) {
        var rowIndex = parseInt(match[1]);
        var axisLabel = data.getValue(rowIndex, 0);
        // do something with the rowIndex and/or axisLabel
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle with example code you can play with to test this: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/fwGmS/