# Pull hyperlinks from Spreadsheet to table on dashboard

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dashboard

I have data in a spreadsheet that I am using and some of the fields are hyperlinked to go to another page. When I pull the data to a table on a dashboard, the hyperlink is gone. I need the hyperlinks to stay functional within the app.

Code I am working with is below:

```js
function doGet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BMFFT2oj9QCwOiMnSQ7YbfrJwGz6x7Q9Kf7h-_IyI5Q');
  var data = ss.getDataRange();


  var dowFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();
  var yearFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(3).build();
  var monthFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(4).build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
    .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([1,2,4,5,6,9,7,8]))
    .setDimensions(800, 400)
    .getFormulas()
    .build();


 var lineChart = Charts.newLineChart()
     .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                            .setColumns([1,8,9]))
     .setDimensions(800, 400)
     .setTitle('Email Open and Click Rate')
     .setXAxisTitle('Date')
     .setYAxisTitle('Rates')
     .build();

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
    .bind([dowFilter, yearFilter, monthFilter], [tableChart, lineChart])
    .build();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(dowFilter).add(yearFilter).add(monthFilter).setSpacing(10);
  chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(lineChart).setSpacing(10);


  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Charts Service in Google Apps Script is a wrapper for the [Google Visualization library](https://developers.google.com/chart/), but it does not support all its capabilities. Embedded HTML is one example of that. You can't do this using the Charts Service.

Instead, you'd need to use the HtmlService, and call the Visualization Library form your client-side JavaScript.

See [Insert Links into Google Charts api data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701772/insert-links-into-google-charts-api-data) for examples of adding clickable links to chart components.

For the work of moving your existing design over, please see my blog [Converting from UiApp + Chart Service to Html Service + Google Visualization API](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/).