# Link within Google chart

Tags: java, google-visualization

I know you can link out from a Google Chart based on this:
[How to add links in google chart api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205621/how-to-add-links-in-google-chart-api)

However, I have parameter that I have stored in the "f" property of the Javascript Literal Notation that I want to use to send to a dynamic link.  For example, my data looks like:

```
  "Load Time":
{"cols":[{"id":"date","label":"Date","type":"string"},
         {"id":"First View","label":"First View","type":"number"},
 "rows":[{"c":[{"f":"130303_67_C", "v":"2013-02-26"},{"v":3.565},{"v":2.495}]},
         {"c":[{"f":"130304_R6_C", "v":"2013-02-27"},{"v":3.6550000000000002},{"v":2.63}]}]},
```

My question is how can I retrieve the value in "f" to use as a parameter for my link which will look like http://www.example.com?testId=

Comment: No, the value in "v" will not work as it is not the ID I need.  Right, I was just including the part of the notation that needed to be referenced for this question.

Comment: Okay, the function I answered with should return the value you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will return the formatted value you require:
`data.getFormattedValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0)`

More about this function can be read at these links:

- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events
- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFormattedValue